# Visio Drawing Control: Some events not responding after closing modal dialog

Tags: multithreading, winforms, modal-dialog, visio, showdialog

I have 2 shapes in the main form. shapes have a context menu item "dummy" which is linked to a queue marker event. It opens a modal form using ShowDialog(). When I close it, some events are not responding.
Right-click doesn't work. shape selection works if you try repeatedly.
Mouse movement works.

I am doing a Dispose() on the modal form.
below is the code. I am using Visio 2019. But this happens with latest visio subscription as well. I have x64 machine. .net is 4+

Please help me with this.

```
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Dialog: Form
    {
        public Dialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            axDrawingControl1.Src = "";
            axDrawingControl1.Document.Application.MarkerEvent += Application_MarkerEvent;

            Visio.Shape shape = axDrawingControl1.Document.Application.ActivePage.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
            shape.AddSection((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction);
            shape.AddRow((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction, 0, (short)Visio.VisRowTags.visTagDefault);
            shape.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction, 0, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visActionMenu].FormulaU = "\"Dummy\"";
            shape.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction, 0, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visActionAction].FormulaU = $"QUEUEMARKEREVENT(\"abc\")";

            shape = axDrawingControl1.Document.Application.ActivePage.DrawOval(0, 0, 1, 1);
            shape.AddSection((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction);
            shape.AddRow((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction, 0, (short)Visio.VisRowTags.visTagDefault);
            shape.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction, 0, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visActionMenu].FormulaU = "\"Dummy\"";
            shape.CellsSRC[(short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction, 0, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visActionAction].FormulaU = $"QUEUEMARKEREVENT(\"def\")";
        }

        private void Application_MarkerEvent(Visio.Application app, int SequenceNum, string ContextString)
        {
            Dialog dlg = null;
            dlg = new Dialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog();
            //I close form
            dlg.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do all events work properly, if you don't open the `Dialog`?

Comment: Yes everything works before ShowDialog

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the

dlg.Dispose()

at that point, in fact that is probably what is causing the problem. The dispose will happen when you do a OK or Cancel on the form. Until then you still need the dlg object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=net-5.0

This suggests using Dispose().
I tried without it, didn't help

Comment: That shows using Dispose() after the dialog has been displayed and the user has finished using it.

Comment: I think the way ShowDialog works is it blocks the main form app until you close it.
After I close then the next statement is executed. please correct if I am wrong.